# Writing and Reading Integer/String Array Values to File (Android Application Development)

Tags: java, android, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write & read integer arrays RED[] and BLUE[] to a file. I've tried converting them into strings and writing them, hoping that it would work, but no luck there. Am I on the right track? I've tried DataOutputStreams but that hasn't worked out for me either.

As of now I'm certain that something isn't right since neither buttons are responsive. The program isn't going through either of the try{}.

**Writing onto File**

```
bSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String FILENAME = name.getText().toString();

                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
                    bw.write(Arrays.toString(paletteview.RED));
                    bw.write(Arrays.toString(paletteview.BLUE));
                    fos.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Reading from File**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String data=null;
                String FILENAME = savedarray[position];

                try {
                    String inputLine = null;
                    StringBuilder sb = null;

                    fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
                    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(br.readLine());
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    data=sb.toString();
                    text.setText(data);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Reading from File: Try #2 (Added textview to see what I read)**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    String data=null;
    String FILENAME = savedarray[position];
    File f = new File(FILENAME);
    if (f.exists) {
        textview.setText(FileManager.readFromFile(f));
    }
}
```

**Writing to File: Try #2**  (for intArrayToString Method, refer to below)

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (name.getText().toString() != null){
            FILENAME = name.getText().toString();
            File f = new File(FILENAME);
            FileManager.writeToFile(f, intArrayToString(paletteview.RED));
        }
    }
```

**intArrayToString (used in Writing to File #2)**

```
String intArrayToString(int[] array) {
    String text = "" + array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        text += ","+array[i];
    }
    return text;
```

*** File Manager (copied from NoInspiration's answer)**

Comment: anything in your logcat?

Comment: In short, the `Arrays.toString()` method does not work as you think. Try `Log.d("debug", Arrays.toString(paletteview.RED)` and you'll see.

Comment: @ScaryWombat nothing in logcat

Comment: @TactMayers sorry, what do I do after that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this class for write and read strings in files :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

/**
 * The <b>FileManager</b> class is a static class used to save <b>File</b> from
 * <b>String</b> and load <b>File</b> as <b>String</b>.
 * 
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class FileManager {

    /**
     * Load a <b>File</b> as a <b>String</b>.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            The file to load
     * @return The File as a String
     */
    public static String readFromFile(final File file) {
        String ret = "";

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Write a <b>String</b> as a <b>File</b>.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            The File where the data will be written
     * @param data
     *            The data to write
     */
    public static void writeToFile(final File file, final String data) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                            outputStream);
                    outputStreamWriter.write(data);
                    outputStreamWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.run();
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor of <b>FileManager</b>. <i>Static class should not be
     * instanced</i>
     */
    private FileManager() {
    }
}
```

You can use it this way :

```
FileManager.writeToFile(file, text);
text = FileManager.readFromFile(file);
```

For the `Array` of `int`, you should parse them to transform them in `String` :

Array of int to String :

```
text = "" + intArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length(); i++) {
    text += ","+intArray[i];
}
```

String to Array of int :

```
String[] raw = text.split("[,]");
for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++) {
    intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(raw[i]);
}
```

Comment: Updated my question. I did as you said and now the buttons are responsive. However, I added a textview to see what I read from the file but it doesn't show anything. When I click the button, the textview updates from the default text to nothing. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: For your file, change it to :
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);

Comment: Also, put a condition : `if(file.exists())` before your `readFromFile` if you want to handle that.

Comment: Looks like the file doesn't exist when I try to read it. 
I tried changing it to: File f = new File(this.getFilesDir(), FILENAME); in Reading to File #2 but it gives me an error telling to create a getFilesDir() method.

Comment: I tried: File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(),FILENAME);. Now it seems that the file exists, but when I read it, it comes out as nothing.

Comment: Silly me, I only changed that on read file but not on write. now it works! Thank you!